# IP regex mask not working in WPF

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, textbox, ip

I read questions about IP mask but haven't found an answer
I'm trying to write a textbox in wpf with using regex to validate IP. This is my xaml code
This code is working

```
<TextBox wpfApplication2:Masking.Mask="^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$"/>
```

I can write 192 or 255 or 29, for example
After that I want to add a dot character. And this crash my code. So I expecting that I can write 
192. or 255. or 29. 
I think that problem in brackets, but can't understand how to resolve it. There are my incorrect solutions:

```
<TextBox wpfApplication2:Masking.Mask="^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[.]$"/>
```

and

```
<TextBox wpfApplication2:Masking.Mask="^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[.])$"/>
```

I'm sure that mistake is very silly but can't find it

**UPDATE**
Thanks for @stribizhev, who gave explanation and answer for IP address. 
Just for my aquestion: I should use {0,1} after [.]. So correct answer for my question (how to create mask for numbers 192. or 255. or 29.) is

```
<TextBox wpfApplication2:Masking.Mask="^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.){0,1}$"/>
```

Comment: Why do you need a `[.]`? It matches a literal dot.

Comment: I need a IP mask and want to define it step by step. I found that this mask is for IP 
^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
But it doesn't work. That's why I decided to try write it step by step

Comment: I guess you need [`@"^(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f%3a%5b0-9%5d%7c%5b1-9%5d%5b0-9%5d%7c1%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d%7c2%5b0-4%5d%5b0-9%5d%7c25%5b0-5%5d)(%3f%3a%5c.(%3f%3a%5b0-9%5d%7c%5b1-9%5d%5b0-9%5d%7c1%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d%7c2%5b0-4%5d%5b0-9%5d%7c25%5b0-5%5d))%7b3%7d%24&i=12.0.0.255). Do you?

Comment: Have you considered using System.Net.IPAddress.Parse() ?

Comment: "this crash my code" -- What does this mean? What happens?

Comment: Please provide some sample input which you want to accept and some which you don't want accepted.

Comment: "Crash" means that I can't input any characters to textbox, but I should have ability write digits which are satisfy my mask

Comment: I update question with examples

Comment: @Bashnia007 fair enough, just thought it could be helpful  as I use it myself. But obviously someone didn't think so.

Comment: You want to say you are performing *live* validation. Right? Then, know that you need to validate a string live with one regex, and perform final validation with another. You cannot use one for both. Try [`^(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])?){0,3}$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f%3a%5b0-9%5d%7c%5b1-9%5d%5b0-9%5d%7c1%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d%7c2%5b0-4%5d%5b0-9%5d%7c25%5b0-5%5d)(%3f%3a%5c.(%3f%3a%5b0-9%5d%7c%5b1-9%5d%5b0-9%5d%7c1%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d%7c2%5b0-4%5d%5b0-9%5d%7c25%5b0-5%5d)%3f)%7b0%2c3%7d%24&i=12.0.12.1).

Comment: I do not think anyone could think it is not useful, just the way you put it does not look like an answer, but a comment.

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks! It works. But I don't understand yet why

Comment: Good, I will post it then with explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the regex you can use for *live validation* (not for *final* one):

```
^(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])?){0,3}$
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3A%5B0-9%5D%7C%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C1%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%7C2%5B0-4%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C25%5B0-5%5D)(%3F%3A%5C.(%3F%3A%5B0-9%5D%7C%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C1%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%7C2%5B0-4%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C25%5B0-5%5D)%3F)%7B0%2C3%7D%24&i=12.0.12.1)

The main point when writing a regex for live validation is to make parts optional. It can be done with `*`, `?` and `{0,x}` quantifiers. Here is a regex break-down:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])` - this is the first number, it is obligatory, but if you plan to let the value be empty, add a `?` at the end
- `(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])?){0,3}` - a sequence of 0 to 3 occurrences of....

  - `\.` - a literal dot (in a verbatim string literal, the one with `@"..."`)
  - `(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])?` - a sequence of the numbers allowed, 1 or 0 occurence (as there is `?` at the end)
- `$` - end of string

For *final* validation, use

```
^(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$
```

See [another demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3A%5B0-9%5D%7C%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C1%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%7C2%5B0-4%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C25%5B0-5%5D)(%3F%3A%5C.(%3F%3A%5B0-9%5D%7C%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C1%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%7C2%5B0-4%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C25%5B0-5%5D))%7B3%7D%24&i=12.0.0.255)

This regex checks the whole, final IP string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accept **any IP address** as a subnet mask:

```
var num = @"(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})";
var rx = new Regex("^" + num + @"\." + num + @"\." + num + @"\." + num + "$");
```

I considered easier to split the "repeating" match for a single group of numbers in a separate variable.

As an exercise for the reader, I'll give another variant of the expression. This one will capture all the numbers in the same group but different captures:

```
var rx = new Regex("^(?:" + num + @"(?:\.(?!$)|$)){4}$");
```

but it's wrong, you should use this

```
var num = @"(255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0+)";
var rx = new Regex("^" + num + @"\." + num + @"\." +num + @"\." +num + "$");
```

or

```
var rx = new Regex("^(?:" + num + @"(?:\.(?!$)|$)){4}$");
```

http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/Course/Subnet/6.htm